# Qt QML LevelAdjust shows strange edge effects when applied to svg source

Tags: qt, svg, qml

When applying a LevelAdjust effect to an image, Qt doesn't seem to handle the edges properly.

I have a set of svg icons, all drawn in black. I would like to change their color easily on the fly.
I am experimenting with the LevelAdjust effect from QtGraphicalEffects 1.12. According to the doc, using minimumOutput should shift the color curve in a linear fashion: blacks will correspond to minimumOutput, white will be white, and colors in between will be a prorated version of minimumOutput.

If I try the following:

```
Rectangle {
  height: 100
  width: 100

  Image {
    id: iconImage
    source: "qrc:/images/circles.svg"
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    width: 0.8 * parent.width
    height: width
    sourceSize.width: width
    sourceSize.height: width
    fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
  }

  LevelAdjust {
    anchors.fill: iconImage
    source: iconImage
    minimumOutput: "#0098FE8F"
  }
}
```

with my svg being as simple as possible:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg version="1.0" viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" fill-rule="evenodd" style="paint-order:normal"/>
</svg>
```

then the inside of the circle takes the expected colour. However, the edges are simply wrong. When rendering the circle, it looks like Qt does some anti-aliasing. But these extra pixels are ignored. I end up with edges which look wrong, but are also darker than the new colour (magnified result here):

[image: resulting image]

I would have expected their colour to be shifted as needed too.
The result is the same on windows, and Android. Am I doing anything wrong?

---

**Edit on 2019/09/05:**

Based on the accepted answer and suggestion below, I created the following ColoredImage.qml component:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.12

Item {
  id: imageWrapper
  property bool colored: true
  property string color: "#FFFF0000"
  // Replicate some Image properties:
  property string source
  property var fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
  property var status: image.status
  property real progress: image.progress

  Image {
    id: image
    source: imageWrapper.source
    anchors.fill: parent
    sourceSize.width: width
    sourceSize.height: height
    fillMode: imageWrapper.fillMode
    visible: !imageWrapper.colored
  }

  ColorOverlay {
    id: overlay
    anchors.fill: image
    source: image
    color: imageWrapper.color
    visible: imageWrapper.colored
  }
}
```

Thanks again!

Comment: Not an answer to the exact question asked, but if you are trying to set SVG icon colors (as opposed to adjusting their levels), I would recommend doing exactly what you're doing now, but use a ColorOverlay instead of LevelAdjust - you can set the exact color you want the icon to be. Probably simpler to determine colors. https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtgraphicaleffects-coloroverlay.html

Comment: Great, just followed your advice in my code. I guess that the only limit in the code I'm showing here is that you cannot control the resulting image's opacity in the color code, but need to do it in the item's opacity parameter...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your iconImage, you must set:

`visible: false`

You are seeing the original black icon under the LevelAdjust item through its semi-transparent anti-aliased edges.

Comment: This never crossed my mind, I would have thought the LevelAdjust would also become invisible. Great, thank you!

Comment: I believe you would be correct if the LevelAdjust were the child of iconImage since visibility and opacity transfer from parent to child, but they did not in this case since they are siblings.